# With the Google Analytics Meausrement API, is there a way to avoid duplicate hits?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-api

I am logging GA hit events and then sending them one at a time directly to the Measurement API endpoints.

It would be convenient to re-start a failed upload process without having to 'remember' which event was the last one sent.

Is it possible to include some kind of 'unique hit ID' or similar in my submissions to the Measurement API that will prevent duplicate hit data if the same hit is sent twice?